# how to properly use math.pow java function?

Tags: java

here's what I'm trying to do:
get two inputs from user and validate them. 1 is a random number between 1 and 20, the other is the times it should multiply itself over ( a number between 1 and 10 which I expressed through exponentiation)

what I don't understand - math.pow only works with doubles? Also, is it possible that the user inputs "wrong" values and instead of terminating, the program asks for inputs again?

I have this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class P01Multiplicador {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("insert number and how many times it will multiply itself over");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int nReps = in.nextInt();

    if(n<1 || n>20 || nReps<1 || nReps>10){
        System.out.println("values are not accepted, please insert again");
    }
    else{
        do Math.pow(n, nReps);
        while(n>1 && n<20 && nReps>1 && nReps<20);

    }
    in.close();

}
```

it asks for the values but doesn't run properly(or, at all for that matter), i'm guessing I'm either using the wrong statements or wrong variable type. java newbie here. suggestions?

Comment: `math.pow only works with doubles?` yes `is it possible that the user inputs "wrong" values and instead of terminating, the program asks for inputs again` yes

Comment: You are no assigning the Math.pow return. So i Guess it will run for ever.
you should do something like "double power = Math.pow(n,nReps);"and use it in the while statement or update the value of n and nReps

Comment: It's an endless loop, because you never update `n` and `nReps`

Comment: This code will run forever. Just add a way to use n nReps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.pow` accepts doubles and returns double as per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29).

For your code to take new inputs when wrong numbers are entered, you can add a `while(true)` loop.

```
while(true){
    if(n<1 || n>20 || nReps<1 || nReps>10){
        System.out.println("values are not accepted, please insert again");
        n = in.nextInt();
        nReps = in.nextInt();
    }
    else{
        System.out.println(Math.pow(n, nReps));
        break;
    }
}
```

I have used `break` to end the loop when correct values are given, but you could get new inputs instead of breaking (as it seems from your code). You need to then have some other break condition otherwise it will be an infinite loop again.

Comment: kept the "while(true)" suggestion, did my own tweaking and it works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to fix your code so it is valid code.

Math.pow uses doubles as it produces both large and tiny numbers depending on the inputs. e.g. even 4^20 will not fit in an `int`.

If you want to round the result to a `long` you can use `Math.round(x)`

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
boolean accepted = false;
do{
 System.out.println("insert number ....

 if(n<1 || n>20 || nReps<1 || nReps>10){
    System.out.println("values are not accepted, please insert again");
 }else{
    accepted = true;
 }
}while( !accepted )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code inside your main method

```
    System.out.println("insert number and how many times it will multiply itself over");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    int nReps = in.nextInt();

    while (true) {
        if (n < 1 || n > 20 || nReps < 1 || nReps > 10) {
            System.out.println("values are not accepted, please insert again");
            System.out.println("insert number and how many times it will multiply itself over");
            n = in.nextInt();
            nReps = in.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("" + Math.pow(n, nReps));
            break;
        }

    }
```